# Django Save Path into Variable

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django path that passes the URL I need, but I want to store it into a variable which I can use in a mailing API the path is:
`path('activate/(<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})', views.activate, name='activate'),`

```
"uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(account.pk)),
'token': password_reset_token.make_token(account),
```

I want the string to have a value similar to this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/activate/(NDM%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(as9osn-a59ae3d7196bb1fa693e770fb87f19c1%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)

I am getting this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/activate/NTQ/asbda1-165d68dbe6fee8c47f5099c4ab709c48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using regex-syntax instead of path syntax. You thus should use the [**`re_path(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) to specify a regex, or convert it to a path syntax. We thus can implement this with:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    # ⋮,
    re_path('activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
    # ⋮
]
```